# Javascript/jQuery browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-detection

I'm making a webpage for a browser extension and I want the download button to automatically download the relevant file for the browser the user is on.

I've found that jQuery's `$.browser` feature is now deprecated, so is there an easy way of detecting the user's browser?

Comment: Well there is a replacement https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin . But as far as i know it just reports `webkit` but not if it is chrome, safari or another browser that uses webkit. So probably a server side detection would be better using browscap or similar _library_. And using that to deliver the right extension. That way you would not need javascript to be activated.

Comment: I suggest http://modernizr.com/. You can use it to find if an actual feature is supported. If you want you can detect browser also but I found that more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want information about the browser that your visitor uses, and use it for statistics or displaying information to the user, you can use the [jQuery Browser Plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin).

you can also use - `navigator.userAgent` for detect user browser.

Comment: This jQuery Browser plugin is what I was looking for - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to **detect the features** instead using [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)

**EDIT:**

Then you can do it simply using `navigator.userAgent` (though [parsing needed](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html))

[**Decrypting the User Agent String in JavaScript**](http://odyniec.net/blog/2010/09/decrypting-the-user-agent-string-in-javascript/)

Comment: While it is generally more preferable to detect features than browsers, in this setting OP needs the browser to deliver the correct extension.

Comment: @Sirko You're right. Thanks for pointing it.  Then OP can do it simply with `navigator.userAgent` (parsing needs) right?

Comment: The world of user agent strings is rather complex, if you want to do it right, but this approach might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It can still be a pain with all the browser specific dependencies in old jQuery plugins.

Try using jQBrowser:
http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-browserdetect/

Almost same syntax:

```
$.browser.browser();
$.browser.version.number();
```